# Подписка на событие и передача данных javascript

Tags: javascript, события, javascript-events

Есть следующая задача.

Даны класс `Rabbit` и класс `Hunter`. `Rabbit` может менять свои координаты **x** и **y**. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при изменении координат охотники, созданные через конструктор вне зависимости от их количества могли получать эти координаты, то есть были подписаны на изменения в `Rabbit`. Код выглядит так:

```
'use strict';

class Rabbit {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
  }

  move() {
    this.x = (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(0);
    this.y = (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(0);
    console.log(this.x, this.y, this.name + ' ' + 'moved');
  }
}

class Hunter {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

let rabbit = new Rabbit("Jonny");

rabbit.move();

let hunter1 = new Hunter("Ted");
let hunter2 = new Hunter("Billy");
let hunter3 = new Hunter("Greg");
```

Полагаю, что классу `Hunter` нужен какой-нибудь метод `notification`, а классу `Rabbit` передавался массив подписчиков, которым нужно передать данные, но как это реализовать, не пойму.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
class Rabbit {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.handlersMove = [];
  }

  move() {
    this.x = (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(0);
    this.y = (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(0);
    console.log(this.x, this.y, this.name + ' ' + 'moved');
    this.handlersMove.forEach(handler => handler(this));
  }
}

class Hunter {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  onGameMoves(game) {
    console.log(`${this.name} sees that ${game.constructor.name} ${game.name} moved to (${game.x}, ${game.y}).`);
  }
}

let rabbit = new Rabbit("Jonny");

let hunter1 = new Hunter("Ted");
rabbit.handlersMove.push(hunter1.onGameMoves.bind(hunter1));
let hunter2 = new Hunter("Billy");
let hunter3 = new Hunter("Greg");
rabbit.handlersMove.push(hunter3.onGameMoves.bind(hunter3));

rabbit.move();
```

Comment: А есть ли способ например сделать какой-то общий метод подписки для всех охотников? Например, чтобы можно было их легко подписывать и отписывать при любом количестве. Ведь если я правильно понимаю, то этот push надо после каждого объявления нового охотника делать.

Comment: @АлисаГулий Ну, можно завести глобальные (статические) списки всех охотников и всей дичи. Охотник в конструкторе будет подписываться ко всем существующим зайцам, а заяц в конструкторе будет подписывать к себе всех существующих охотников.

Answer (score 2):

Вы в своём вопросе на него же и ответили, воспользуйтесь шаблоном [публикатор-подписчик](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Все это выглядит примерно так:

Где то в начале создаётся глобальный объект, назовём его `broker` который имеет 2 метода `fire`(отправить событие) и `on`(подписаться на событие)

```
let broker = new Broker();
```

Затем все Hunter при создании подписываются на событие `rabbit-moved`

```
broker.on("rabbit-moved", hunt)
```

Тут я предположил что у охотника есть метод `hunt(eventContext)` в котором находится код логики охоты

Когда произойдёт изменение координат какого либо Rabbit, то есть внутри вашего метода `Rabbit.move()` вы отправляете событие `rabbit-moved`

```
broker.fire("rabbit-moved", eventContext)
```

Вторым аргументом тут идёт объект, который будет содержать всю необходимую информацию об обработке этого события, в нашем случае это `x` и `y` наших кроликов.

Брокер отправляет это сообщение всем подписчикам,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

topic - на картинке выше, это имя нашего события

Сам брокер может отличаться тяжестью случая, самая простая версия выглядит примерно [так](https://github.com/strangerintheq/d3-paint-app/blob/master/src/app/broker.js)

---

```js
class Broker {
  constructor() {
    // массивы подписчиков привязанные к каждому топику
    this.subscribers = {};
  }

  // метод подписки
  on(topic, func) {
    if (!this.subscribers[topic])
      this.subscribers[topic] = [];
    this.subscribers[topic].push(func);
  }

  // метод оповещения подписчиков
  fire(topic, data) {
    if (this.subscribers[topic])
      this.subscribers[topic].forEach(l => l(data));
  }
}
   
// создаётся глобальный объект, который связывает публикаторов и подписчиков
let broker = new Broker();

class Rabbit {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.handlersMove = [];
  }

  move() {
    this.x = (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(0);
    this.y = (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(0);
    // все кролики в момент перемещение публикуют событие
    broker.fire('rabbit-moved', this);
  }
}

class Hunter {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    // все охотники подписаны на топик "rabbit-moved" 
    // и когда приходит данное событие вызывается метод hunt
    broker.on('rabbit-moved', data => this.hunt(data))
  }

  hunt(data) {
    console.log(`Hunter ${this.name}: I saw ${data.name} at ${data.x}:${data.y}`);
  }
}

// создаем 10 кроликов и 2 охотника
let rabbits = Array(10).fill(0).map((e, i) => new Rabbit(`Rabbit ${i+1}`));
new Hunter("Tom")
new Hunter("Max")


function moveRandomRabbit() {
  // перемещение случайного кролика в случайную точку
  rabbits[Math.floor(Math.random() * rabbits.length)].move();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="moveRandomRabbit()">move random rabbit</button>
```

Comment: а брокер как будет следить за зайцами?

Comment: @Grundy ну я же написал, сами зайцы отправляют событие... "Когда произойдёт изменение координат какого либо Rabbit вы отправляете событие rabbit-moved", слегка подправил ответ

Comment: Отправляют в брокер? или брокер внутри зайца? можно схему как эти три класса между собой взаимодействуют?

Comment: @Grundy брокер - глобальный объект, все правильно, все про него знают и зайцы и охотники

Comment: то есть охотники при создании вызывают broker.on, зайцы при move  - broker.fire?

Comment: @Grundy ну да, я разве как то иначе написал?)

Comment: Честно говоря, из текста я не понял :-)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а можно комментарии к коду?

Comment: @Demon__ANT немного написал

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо +1